# When generating code for arm64, why do gcc + clang use adrp+add rather than adr for addressing nearby variables?

Tags: gcc, clang, arm64

With arm64, a literal for a nearby address can be loaded into a register with the *adr* instruction. According to the ARM-V8 Architecture Reference Manual the *adr* instruction:

```
ADR <Xd>, <label>   Address of label at a PC-relative offset
```

can reference labels within +/-1MB. There is a page version with bit-31 set, *adrp*, for constructing larger offsets.

What I don't understand is why neither [gcc 8.2](https://godbolt.org/z/y0gBuJ) nor [clang 7.0](https://godbolt.org/z/1VuO1a) for ARM64 use *adr* rather than an *adrp* and *add* pair for nearby variables. Optimization levels don't change this.

```
int write(int fd, const void *buf, int count);

void xyz(void)
{
    write(2, "abc", 4);
}

xyz(): // @xyz()
  adrp x1, .L.str
  add x1, x1, :lo12:.L.str
  orr w0, wzr, #0x2
  orr w2, wzr, #0x4
  b write(int, void const*, int)
.L.str:
  .asciz "abc"
```

Can they not reason that this string literal is within +/-1MB? Is there a compiler attribute/switch to tell them this?

Comment: Are you compiling with `-O3`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GCC will generate such code with [`-mcmodel=tiny`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/AArch64-Options.html#index-mcmodel_003dtiny):

```
    .global xyz
    .type   xyz, %function
xyz:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    mov w2, 4
    adr x1, .LC0
    mov w0, 2
    b   write
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   xyz, .-xyz
    .section    .rodata.str1.8,"aMS",@progbits,1
    .align  3
.LC0:
    .string "abc"
```